# Error "Service not found" when trying to authenticate user in React app with Express.js backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, auth0

I'm currently working on a React application with an Express.js backend where I'm trying to authenticate users using the Auth0 package. I have a setup where the frontend and backend communicate through API requests.

In my React app, I'm encountering an error: "Service not found: http://localhost:5000" when trying to make a request from the frontend to the backend after obtaining an access token. I've checked the configurations and URLs, but I can't seem to pinpoint the issue.

Here's the relevant code:

Frontend: I'm using the useMutation hook to make the API request after obtaining the access token.

```
const { mutate } = useMutation({
  mutationKey: [user?.email],
  mutationFn: async (token) => {
    try {
      await ApiInstance.post(
        Endpoints.createUser,
        {
          email: user?.email,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("An error occurred:", error);
      throw error;
    }
  },
});
```

Backend: I'm using the express-oauth2-jwt-bearer package to perform JWT token validation.

```
import { auth } from "express-oauth2-jwt-bearer";

export const jwtCheck = auth({
  audience: "http://localhost:5000",
  issuerBaseURL: "https://MY_DOMAIN.auth0.com",
  tokenSigningAlg: "RS256",
});
```

I've verified that the URLs, CORS configuration, and token audience match on both the frontend and backend. The Express.js server is running on http://localhost:5000.

This is the error I'm getting
[image]

What could be causing this "Service not found" error? Are there any common pitfalls or misconfigurations I should be aware of when setting up this type of authentication flow between a React app and an Express.js backend?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!